# regex extract code from <body>...</body>?

Tags: regex, html-parsing, regex-lookarounds

how to capture all codes inside the html .... in regex format? currently I tried several codes but it is not capturing all, I tried this

```
<body>([^*]*)<\/body>
```

but it didnt capture all codes because some javascript code is affecting the regex command.

do you know any link or sample to solve this issue?

TIA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would likely capture anything between standard `<body>` tags

```
(?:<body>((?s).*)<\/body>)
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/iS4eE3

Comment: it will not work if `<body anything="yes"`

Comment: @MuhammadSanaullah of course not, why would it?

Comment: I commented not for you, I commented for those who are new to regex, they will use this regex code and wonder why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
'#<body>(.*?)<\/body>#s'
```